# Lock the value of a cell after first edit script running and don't update the cell value for other edits

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a script that automatically fills cells on a Google Spreadsheet every time Col3 or Col16 is edited by someone.

#### My issue:

If someone edits or modifies the value in Col3, the timestamp in the automated cells will be updated while I'd like to keep the first value in those cells, the generated date when Col 3 has been edited for the first time.

#### My script:

```
function onEdit(event) {
  // assumes source data in sheet named Elisa-Miriam-Victor-Hanane-Sarah-Apoorva-Carlino
  // target sheet of move to named Archive
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s = event.source.getActiveSheet();
  var r = event.source.getActiveRange();

  // Fill automatically Columns Q and R when PO number is provided in Column P.
  // In Q: generates the date of when the PO is mentioned; in R: it generates the PO folder name
  var sh=event.range.getSheet();
  var namesA=["Miriam","Elisa","Hanane","Sarah","Apoorva","Victor","Carlino"];
if(namesA.indexOf(sh.getName())!=-1 && event.range.columnStart==16) { // when PO 1 N° is filled
     event.range.offset(0,1).setValue(new Date()).setNumberFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
     event.range.offset(0,2).setFormula(Utilities.formatString('=CONCATENATE(TEXT(Q%s;"yyyy-MM-dd");" - ";P%s)',event.range.rowStart,event.range.rowStart,event.range.rowStart));
   }         

if(namesA.indexOf(sh.getName())!=-1 && event.range.columnStart==3) { // when client is mentioned in Col 3
  event.range.offset(0,9).setFormula(Utilities.formatString('=IFERROR(vlookup(E%s;IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1zN99rXMltbMfD_OS22NxZApgvabTG-eRv7FOIS7pBvk/edit#gid=1560028291";"Treatment!A:E");2;false);"")',event.range.rowStart,event.range.rowStart,event.range.rowStart));
     event.range.offset(0,31).setValue(new Date()).setNumberFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
   }
  }
```

**Does any one have an idea of how I can lock the first generated value for the dates?**

Thank you for your help,

Comment: What do you mean by the first time perhaps you mean the first time each day the first time each week the first time after summer event or simply the first time after you get through programming which is it

Comment: By first time, I mean: I fill Col3 by the client name, this value isn't supposed to change going forward. But if I need to modify the client name (either formatting or content), the generated cells will update the timestamp at the date of today, while I'd like to keep the date when I filled the client name for the first time

Comment: You could use PropertiesService with a script that only stores data in that property if there isn't such a property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### You can check either the cell is empty before assigning to it a value:

```
function onEdit(event) {
     ...
     var offsetRange = event.range.offset(0,31);
     if(offsetRange.isBlank()){
       offsetRange.setValue(new Date()).setNumberFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    }
   }
  }
```

Comment: This is perfect, it's working. Thank you ziganotschka

Answer (score 0):

Save First Time Only

```
function saveFirstTimeOnly(key,value) {
  const ps=PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
  var obj=ps.getProperties();
  if(!obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    ps.setProperty(key, value);    
  }
}
```

You can use anything for the key. Like perhaps the 'SheetName' + 'RangeInA1Notation' and you may have to use an installable trigger for this not sure.

Comment: I've used the other solution because it didn't need another trigger but thank you for your help Cooper!